# Installing xv6 on a macOSX catalina

Tags: macos, gcc, zsh, qemu, xv6

I'm trying to run the XV6 on mac os,
I followed the following [instructions](https://pdos.csail.mit.edu/6.828/2019/tools.html)

I have already added `export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/opt/riscv-gnu-toolchain/bin` to the `.zshrc` file. (I'm using zsh)
But when I'm trying to run `make qemu`
I'm still getting  `Error: Couldn't find a riscv64 version of GCC/binutils.`

What I'm missing here?

Comment: Did you restart `zsh` after modifying `.zshrc`? Can you execute `riscv64-unknown-elf-gcc`

Comment: @Mathieu, Yes, I restarted and I'm still getting 'zsh: command not found: riscv64-unknown-elf-gcc'

Comment: So, something went wrong when installing ` brew install riscv-tools`, could you check that ?

Comment: @Mathieu I re-installed the riscv-tools and all is working now, Thanks!